# JNI why jintArray cannot be considered as [I instead of Ljava/lang/Object?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, signature

I'm curious about the following code snippet:

```
jintArray someJIntArray;
jfloatArray someJFloatArray;

// ... put legit values to someJIntArray and someJFloatArray

jclass pairClass = env->FindClass("android/util/Pair");

// #1
jmethodID pairConstructor = env->GetMethodID(pairClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V");

// #2
jmethodID pairConstructor = env->GetMethodID(pairClass, "<init>", "([I[F)V");

jobject pairObject = env->NewObject(pairClass, pairConstructor, someJIntArray, someJFloatArray);
```

If I use `#1` , then my JNI code runs okay. But if I use `#2` then `Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/util/Pair;.<init>([I[F)V"` error occurs.

I wonder, why I cannot use `[I` and `[F` for `jintArray` and `jfloatArray`? Actually I'm also curious why `Ljava/lang/Object;` works in this code snippet while `int` and `float` are not objects in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically asking for it to find the constructor `Pair(int[], float[])`, which doesn't exist.

It's not about the value you are going to pass in, but about the types of the formal parameters.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. May I ask why it is not `java/lang/Object` but `Ljava/lang/Object`? In the API document, `android.util.Pair` gets objects as input, not arrays of objects.

Comment: `L` means a class type; `[` means an array type.